# help in clarifying equivalence of $L^2$ as a completion space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm taking a course in functional analysis and it is not a pre-requisite to 
know measure theory and Lebesgue integral so the way we define $L^2(I)$ is as the completion of $C_0(I)$ - the space of continuous functions on $I$ with compact support, equipped with the inner product: $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_{I} f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$

I know it is not the usual approach for working with the space $L^2(I)$.

we have been talking in class about other constructions of $L^2(I)$ as a completion of other inner product spaces for example we looked at $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$ - the space of equivalence classes of piecewise continuous functions on $I$ with compact support under the equivalence relation: $f\thicksim g \iff \int_{I} f(x)dx=\int_{I} g(x)dx$ , equipped with the inner product: $\langle [f],[g]\rangle =\int_{I} f(x)g(x)dx$ where $f$ and $g$ are some reprasentatives for $[f]$ and $[g]$.

We wrote in class the following statement:

$L^2(I)$ (defined as the completion of $C_0(I)$) is equivalent to the completion of $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$

which from what I understood in class means that $L^2(I)$ is equal to the completion of $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$
and we proved this by taking some cauchy sequence in $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$ and find a cauchy sequence in $C_0(I)$ such that the metric of these two sequence approaches zero.

and now for my question: I feel that the above statement and how we proved it in class missing some details for it to be formal. for example how can one take the metric of two sequences which are not in the same space and thus the metric is not defined to act on them. I know that $C_0(I)$ is a subspace of $PC_0(I)$ but it is not a subspace of $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$ so how can I complete the picture for this statement to make sense? what is the formal way to say the above statement and what is the formal procedure to prove this?

sorry for any grammar mistakes and thanks for any clarification.

Comment: To be safe you can show that they are not the same but isomorphic spaces. For example you can show that you can embed $C_0(I)$ in $P\tilde{C}_0(I)$ by sending a function to its class.

Comment: @Mathematician42 suppose that $\varphi$ is the embedding of $C_0(I)$ in $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$ and that I proved that the completion of $\varphi(C_0(I))$ and the completion of $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$ are the same. how can I conclude from this that $L^2(I)$ and the completion of $\tilde{PC_0(I)}$ are isomorphic spaces? sorry if this question is dumb but I'm just not that practiced on this subject.

Comment: That is not a dumb question. You have that $C_0(I)\cong \phi(C_0(I))$ and you need that the completion of $C_0(I)$ is isomorphic to the completion of $\phi(C_0(I))$. So it would be nice if in general you could show that the completion of isomorphic spaces is isomorphic.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I agree that is fact would be very useful :)
I'll surely try this approach. thank you very much!

Comment: Also by isomorphic I mean distance preserving as well (isometric). Also I guess you can show that $\phi(C_0(I))$ is dense in $L^2(I)$ by considering the Fourier expension of a square integrable function.